# Pass data from one component to another using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have the following in App.js

```
let contracts = [
 {
   id: "1",
   name: "Lloyds",
   image: ""
 }
];

class App extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Header />
       <Search />
       <ContractsList />
       <Content />
       <Footer />
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Im trying to pass the contracts variable as a prop in my index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css";

ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <App contracts={contracts} />
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById("root")
);
```

but keep getting the following error:

```
 Line 10:21:  'contracts' is not defined  no-undef
```

how can i use the contracts variable so it can be used as a prop in other components?

Answer (score 1):

You need to shift your contracts array from app.js to index.js and then pass it as a props.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css";

let contracts = [
 {
   id: "1",
   name: "Lloyds",
   image: ""
 }
];

ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <App contracts={contracts} />
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`contracts` is not defined in your index.js file. Either you define contracts there, or you import it.

And then, you need to pass it to the underlying components in App.js too, for example:

```
<Content contracts={this.props.contracts} />
```

(For every component in which you need it.) Why are you trying to pass it in `index.js` at all?

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming on the `index.js` file on this line:

```
 <App contracts={contracts} />
```

here you dont have any variable called `contracts`, you may need to put a variable `contracts` in this file instead of `App.js`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You've defined contracts in a different file to the one you're trying to use it in. Define `contracts` in index.js and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to export the contracts

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-http-plq9c)

**App.js**

```
export const contracts = [
 {
   id: "1",
   name: "Lloyds",
   image: ""
 }
];
```

**index.js**

```
import App,{contracts} from "./App";
```

> ***For better.*** its already in `app.js` . so you can access with in app.js .no need to pass from `index.js`